# cppitertools: How to combine iter::enumerate and iter::filter?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

Consider this example (using [`cppitertools`](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <cppitertools/enumerate.hpp>
#include <cppitertools/filter.hpp>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    auto f = iter::enumerate(v) | iter::filter([](auto& i) { return std::get<1>(i) > 4; });

    for (auto&& [i, e]: f) {
        std::cout << i << ", " << e << '\n';
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is filtering results from `iter::enumerate` (trying to get only values that are `> 4`). Unfortunately, this snippet doesn't compile (g++ 7.4):

Error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::optional<iter::impl::EnumIterYield<long unsigned int, int&> >& std::optional<iter::impl::EnumIterYield<long unsigned int, int&> >::operator=(std::optional<iter::impl::EnumIterYield<long unsigned int, int&> >&&)’

...

error: use of deleted function ‘std::_Enable_copy_move<true, false, true, false, _Tag>& std::_Enable_copy_move<true, false, true, false, _Tag>::operator=(std::_Enable_copy_move<true, false, true, false, _Tag>&&) [with _Tag = std::optional<iter::impl::EnumIterYield<long unsigned int, int&> >]’
```

Expected result:

```
4, 5
5, 6
6, 7
7, 8
```

---

When I remove `iter::enumerate(v)` and do filtering only on plain vector, it works:

```
auto f = v | iter::filter([](auto& i) { return i > 4; });

for (auto&& i: f) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Prints:

```
5
6
7
8
```

Can I filter results of `iter::enumerate()`? I'm suspecting I got the lambda function in `iter::filter` wrong.

Comment: unless you wanted to get indices, nevermind

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yep, exactly. I want indices filtered too...

Comment: `iterbase.hpp:301` should probably read `item_p_.emplace(std::move(item));` , instead of `item_p_ = std::move(item);` . That is, enumerator's iterator holds a pair with a reference type, which is not copy-assignable.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki So it's not possible to combine enumerate and filter? I can do the filtering explicitly in for-loop, but I thought it would be more elegant to combine the iterators...

Comment: Not with how it's currently implemented (probably unintended), but you can fix what I found and test if it works

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I changed it, compiled and it works :) Thanks! Can you write answer - so I can close the question.

Comment: Sure, as soon as I have time, I will investigate it a little bit deeper to make sure I suggested a correct approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iter::enumerate` returns an instance of type `iter::impl::Enumerable`. Its iterator, once dereferenced, returns `iter::impl::EnumIterYield<unsigned long, int&>` which is a class type which derives from `std::pair<unsigned long, int&>`, but also redeclares its own data members, whose `index` (`first`) data member stores the value index, while `element` (`second`) is a reference to the actual value from the container (see `int&`). This is fine, as we want to be able to modify the content of the container through an iterator, and also avoid unnecesary copies:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
auto e = iter::enumerate(v);
std::get<1>(*e.begin()) = 5;
```

This is how the class is implemented:

```
template <typename Index, typename Elem>
using EnumBasePair = std::pair<Index, Elem>;

template <typename Index, typename Elem>
class EnumIterYield : public EnumBasePair<Index, Elem> {
    using BasePair = EnumBasePair<Index, Elem>;
    using BasePair::BasePair;

public:
    typename BasePair::first_type index = BasePair::first;
    typename BasePair::second_type element = BasePair::second;
};
```

However, the `iter::impl::EnumIterYield` type does not declare its own copy/move-assignment operators, which makes objects of this class non-copy-assignable (this will be important later) -- the implicitly declared copy-assignment operator will be therefore defined as deleted if either `index` or `element` are of reference types (or `const`).

Going further, by filtering the result of `iter::enumerate` with `iter::filter`, another object is created, this time of type `iter::impl::Filtered`. Its iterator stores a so called `DerefHolder` named `_item`. `DerefHolder` is supposed to hold inside a dereferenced value of the wrapped iterator:

```
// DerefHolder holds the value gotten from an iterator dereference
// if the iterate dereferences to an lvalue references, a pointer to the
//     element is stored
// if it does not, a value is stored instead
```

That is, `DerefHolder` is specialized for the case when the template argument is a reference type, in which case it stores a (copy-assignable) *pointer*. For non-reference types, an actual *value* is stored in an `std::optional` (referred to as `item_p_`).

Having a specialization of `DerefHolder` for reference types, it is possible to operate on the filtered container values directly using `iter::impl::Filtered::Iterator`.

However, a dereferenced `iter::impl::Enumerable::Iterator` does not result in a reference type. As said before, it is a non-copy-assignable `iter::impl::EnumIterYield<unsigned long, int&>`, which does not trigger the specialization, and instead it causes the compiler to fall back to the primary template of `DerefHolder`. Its `reset()` function, invoked when the first value that should not be filtered-out is found, has the following definition:

```
void reset(T&& item) {
    item_p_ = std::move(item);
}
```

That is, it invokes `std::optional<iter::impl::EnumIterYield<unsigned long, int&>>::operator=`, which in turn tries to copy-assign the problematic `EnumIterYield` (holding a reference type member without an explicitly defined copy/move-assignment operators), failing to do so. This is what the error message reports:

```
error: use of deleted function
```

I see no reason to try to copy-assign the stored value, as it can equally well be re-created, so I suggest to change the implementation to, instead, copy(move)-construct the item stored in `std::optional`:

```
void reset(T&& item) {
    item_p_.emplace(std::move(item));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try to create an issue on cppitertool's github page then.

Comment: How embarrassing. Thanks for the deep dive and [the solution](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/commit/41f7d221fe452dfc198914560355b837423e2a1d)